# How Can I Resolve the "Couldn't resolve parser 'angular'" Error When Using Prettier in StackBlitz?

Tags: angular, prettier

I'm trying to utilize `prettier` in StackBlitz to format HTML in Angular, but I encounter the following error:

> Error: Couldn't resolve parser "angular". Parsers must be explicitly added to the standalone bundle.

I'm uncertain about what's missing. Any assistance would be appreciated.

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-n1vmbc?file=index.ts)

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import prettier from 'prettier';
import parserAngular from 'prettier/parser-angular';
console.clear();

console.log({ parserAngular }); // Checking existence.

const html = `
<span *ngIf="true">
  do {{ some | json: ja }} bla
</span>
`;

const output = prettier.format(html, {
  plugins: [parserAngular],
  parser: 'angular',
  singleQuote: true,
  arrowParens: 'always',
  semi: true,
  bracketSameLine: true,
  trailingComma: 'es5',
  printWidth: 140,
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include `parser-html` in the plugins array:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-awxdq6?file=index.ts)

```
// Import stylesheets
import './style.css';
import prettier from 'prettier';
import parserAngular from 'prettier/parser-angular';
import parserHtml from 'prettier/parser-html';
console.clear();

console.log({ parserAngular });

// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

const html = `
<span *ngIf="true">
  do {{ some | json: ja }} bla
</span>
`;

const output = prettier.format(html, {
  plugins: [parserAngular, parserHtml],
  parser: 'angular',
  singleQuote: true,
  arrowParens: 'always',
  semi: true,
  bracketSameLine: true,
  trailingComma: 'es5',
  printWidth: 140,
});
console.log(output);
```